# How to display KDB row size?

Tags: kdb

[`count`](http://code.kx.com/q/ref/lists/#count) returns the number of elements of a list, or table rows, or the length of a string.
Is there a way to print the size of the row itself? In other words, I want to know the size of a table I loaded in memory, not simply the number of rows.

And what about the total size of a list of strings? Do I have to use [`each`](http://code.kx.com/q/ref/control/#each) to calculate the sum of all string lengths or there is another way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Depending on which version you're using. You can use

```
q)-22!x / 2.7 or later I believe
```

or

```
q)count -8!x
```

So

```
q)tbl:([]ids:10?`1;price:10?100.0)
q)count -8!tbl
145
q)count -8!("one";"two";"three")
43
q)count -8!("one";"two";"three";"4")
45
```

See http://code.kx.com/q/ref/internal/